# Getting autonumbering from Microsoft Word autonumbered styles to show up in a quick part

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, headers

I have chapter headings in a style in Microsoft Word 2007 that is an autonumbered style, so each instance of the style is automatically prefixed Chapter 1, Chapter 2, etc.  So my chapter headings look like:

> Chapter 1: Apples
>
> Chapter 2: Bananas

and so forth.

However, I am trying to create running headers based on the chapter titles and having a really hard time.  I can insert a quick part based on the chapter title styleref, but it picks up only the chapter title, and not the Chapter 1:, Chapter 2:, etc. prefixes, even though they are in the same style.  So my running headers just say Apples, Bananas, etc. when I want them to include the full chapter title as they appear in the text.

Does anyone know how to get the autonumbered component of the autonumbered style to show up in a quick part, or any other way of getting these easily into running headers?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just position your cursor before the text heading you inserted in the header with stlyeref and use styleref again. Select Heading 1 in the styleref dialog box and from the options on the right select "Insert paragraph number."

Comment: Yeah, perfect!  I also found the VBA command activedocument.convertnumberstotext, but this is way better since it lets me keep the autonumbering in place.  Thanks!